# Can you use 2 'using' statements for both sqlconnection and sqldatareader?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Can you use 2 'using' statements like:

```
using (SqlConnection ..)
{
    using(SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader())
    {

     }

}
```

I'm trying to do this put getting an error on the constructor of the SqlDataReader

Comment: What's the error? This should work fine.

Comment: dont' think SqlDataReader has a constructor...hence u can't use new on it

Comment: yeah that constructor was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SqlDataReader has no constructor.  You are returned a datareader by calling the `ExecuteReader` method of a SqlCommand object.

e.g.

```
using (SqlConnection ..) 
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())) 
    { 

    } 

}
```

Comment: FYI: SqlCommand is IDisposable and should be in a using statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can and you can also format them without the extra brackets like so:

```
using (SqlConnection ..)
using(SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader())
{

}
```

Which I do all the time to limit the amount of scope nesting.

Comment: Whatever your error is, it is unrealted to using two using statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a SqlDataReader like that as mentioned above.  Generally I see 2 levels of using blocks, but the inner one would be the command object, something like this:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
 {
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(...))
    {
       var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
 }
```