# Which Namespaces Must Be Used to Connect to SQL Server with ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i am using this example to connect c# to sql server. can you please tell me what i have to include in order to be able to use sqlconnection?

it must be something like:
`using Sqlconnection;` ???

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=""C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases\NORTHWND.MDF"";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
 sqlCon.Open();

string commandString = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
 SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dataReader.Read())
 {
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", dataReader["CompanyName"], dataReader["ContactName"]));
 }
 dataReader.Close();
 sqlCon.Close();
```

Comment: Always use the using statement for using the SqlConnection and SqlDataReader as a best practice. See this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623550/can-you-use-2-using-statements-for-both-sqlconnection-and-sqldatareader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: In the code in the question, none of the classes required System.Data namespace to be included.

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 and use C# then you must provide the following namespace.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Answer (score 2):

One nice trick one when you don't know what namespace to use in `using` statement. Type the classname (e.g. SqlConnection, MemoryStream, FileStream, etc), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.   Though it won't work if the classname doesn't match the case, e.g. Sqlconnection, sqlconnection

Answer (score 1):

Also, check out connectionstrings.com - it's probably the most useful tech website on the internet for making sure your ADO.NET is set up right.

When you decide to move on from just using Northwind, that site will come in handy a bunch. No one I know actually remembers the syntax for a connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the following namespace:-

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```